# core data and reflexive relationship entity

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Ok, i set up a reflexive relationship entity (with help from a [SO question] i posted earlier[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gTaY.png).

I believe i set it up correctly:

[image]

I have an Entity GroupMember. I created a many-to-many relationship to itself.

I then add an entity and create a "sub" entity and set it to the relationship:

```
GroupMember *groupMember = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GroupMember" inManagedObjectContext:context];
groupMember.name = @"Ted";

GroupMember *subGroupMember = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GroupMember" inManagedObjectContext:context];
subGroupMember.name = @"sub member bill";

[groupMember addSub_member_relObject:subGroupMember];
```

I then make a fetch request for any GroupMember entities to see if the relationship was set. what i get back is:

```
fetch objects: (
    "<GroupMember: 0x83cf280> (entity: GroupMember; id: 0x98686b0 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p1> ; data: {\n    \"member_rel\" =     (\n    );\n    name = Ted;\n    \"sub_member_rel\" =     (\n        \"0x989f390 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p2>\"\n    );\n})",
    "<GroupMember: 0x83cf4a0> (entity: GroupMember; id: 0x989f390 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p2> ; data: {\n    \"member_rel\" =     (\n        \"0x98686b0 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p1>\"\n    );\n    name = \"sub member bill\";\n    \"sub_member_rel\" =     (\n    );\n})"
)
2012-12-13 12:08:45.352 [9539:14003] name: Ted
2012-12-13 12:08:45.355 [9539:14003] set: Relationship 'sub_member_rel' on managed object (0x83cf280) <GroupMember: 0x83cf280> (entity: GroupMember; id: 0x98686b0 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p1> ; data: {
    "member_rel" =     (
    );
    name = Ted;
    "sub_member_rel" =     (
        "0x989f390 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p2>"
    );
}) with objects {(
    <GroupMember: 0x83cf4a0> (entity: GroupMember; id: 0x989f390 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p2> ; data: {
    "member_rel" =     (
        "0x98686b0 <x-coredata://D9082F84-03D9-408D-B0DA-5C75C1B905AB/GroupMember/p1>"
    );
    name = "sub member bill";
    "sub_member_rel" =     (
    );
})
)}
```

A) i don't quite understand how to read this output. What is the "with objects" part? is the that the entity with the relationship? Is "sub member bill" set as a sub member relation correctly?

B) when i try to get back the groupMember.Sub_member_rel, i get a NSSet. How do i iterate over these objects to get back the sub member names (to display in a table view)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A)** The output from printing an `NSManagedObject` or its relationships is usually verbose and somewhat complex. In your case, the object to which the relationship belongs is printed first. Then comes the "with objects" part which consists of objects in that particular relationship.

**B)** In a To-Many relationship, the relationship type is always an `NSSet`. Just like with `NSArray` you can iterate through an `NSSet` like this:

```
for (GroupMember *subGroupMember in groupMember.sub_member_rel) {
    // Do something with managedObject
}
```

Comment: And if you need an array as table view data source, you get it via `NSArray *subMembers = [groupMember.sub_member_rel allObjects];`.

Comment: Ha! i was setting sub_member_rel to a NSSet and i couldn't not iterrate through that. ok, this shows a flaw in my logic, i'm seeing "sub member bill" with a subGroupMember of "sub member bill". /boggle  Thank you for your help!