# How to set and fetch objects via reflexive relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

My goal is to be able to start with a given task and be able to create, read, update, and delete children subtasks of that task.

**Progress so far:**

1. I have the task object defined and full CRUD on it
2. I have the subtask relationship and inverse relationship created in Coredata
3. Problem: I'm missing the Coredata fetch/set syntax
4. I know to expect the relationship to return a set and have written the function to turn that into an array that I can create a table from.

**Problem**
I don't know to write a Coredata operation (any CRUD) on a subtask. For example, I haven't added any new attributes. Do I need a "subtask" or "superTask" attribute to pass as a filter to get the right tasks back? When I store a subtask, how do I tell Coredata that this new thing is a subtask and to which parent it belongs?

Knowing that all tasks and subtasks will be one list of objects within the same Task entity, with a reflexive relationship, it seems like I should just add a "parentTaskID" attribute to the Task entity and filter on it. Parent tasks would have nil for that field. However, based on research I've done (see below) it seems like there's a more elegant solution?

Research, code, and screenshots below.

---

**Research**
I've researched this question, read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1) documentation, and found the closest answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867891/core-data-and-reflexive-relationship-entity), and related topics like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885149/core-data-reflexive-to-many-relationships). From these, the reflexive relationship setup is clear and that's what I've done. However, the "how to write to this new layer/reflexive set of tasks" is not something I've found much on.

---

My CoreData model:
[image: My CoreData model]

My "Task" class attributes, including the subtask set:

```
extension Task {

//MARK: - FETCH REQUEST
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Task> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Task>(entityName: "Task")
}

//MARK: - PROPERTIES
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var createdDate: Double
@NSManaged public var desc: String?
@NSManaged public var userInputNumVal: Int64
@NSManaged public var userInputCurrency: String
@NSManaged public var userInputNumIsPos: Bool
@NSManaged public var group: String?
@NSManaged public var section: String?
// @NSManaged public var timesCompleted : Int
@NSManaged public var favorite : Bool
@NSManaged public var displayOrder: Int64
@NSManaged public var dueDate: Date?
// @NSManaged public var photo: Data?
@NSManaged public var starred: Bool
@NSManaged public var list: ListMetaData?
@NSManaged public var photos : Set<Photo>?
@NSManaged public var reminderOffset : Int64
@NSManaged public var lastCompletedDate : Date?

@NSManaged public var superTask : Task?
@NSManaged public var subtasks : Set<Task>?
```

My code for parsing the set into an array:

```
    if let subtasks = taskObject?.subtasks {
        let indices = subtasks.indices
        for eaIndice in indices {
            let subtask = subtasks[eaIndice]
            temp_ArrayOfSubTasks.append(subtask)
        }
    }
```

My "Task" class init function to introduce a new task:

```
    convenience init( _ name: String, desc : String = "", dueDate : Date = Date.distantPast, list : ListMetaData ) {
    if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task", in: Context.moc) {
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: Context.moc)
        self.createdDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.dueDate = dueDate > Date.distantPast ? dueDate : nil
        self.list = list

    } else {
        fatalError("Unable to find Entity Task")
    }
}
```

My context class:

```
class Context {

private static let shared = Context()

static let moc = Context.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

static func saveContext() {
    Context.shared.saveContext()
}

static func listenDidSave(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                           object: Context.moc,
                                           queue: OperationQueue.main) { _ in
        block()
    }
}
```

Could someone provide an example of how I might update my code to handle one or two operations on a subtask? For example, updating the init function to accept a new subtask or updating a subtask within the set to an updated attribute value (for example "isTaskComplete: Bool")? I'm simply unclear on how to work with them.

Comment: You tell core data a task is a sub task by having a parent assigned to it, that’s the definition of a sub task isn’t it? I find the question a bit unclear but in the Create function you should add an optional parent parameter as I see it. And as far as fetching, why use CRUD when you can access the values via the relationship properties.

Comment: When you say  "access the values via the relationship properties", I guess that's where I'm unclear. I added an attribute to my Task class called "subtasks" so I think that taskObject.subtasks will allow me access to subtasks but I'm unsure of how to pass in new subtasks / update the init I shared, how to update a subtask property (complete it, for example), etc. This seems like a whole new set of Coredata syntax that I haven't found good examples of. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Use two convenience init methods, the one you have for the parent and a second one that also takes a Task parameter for creating a sub task and adding it to the parent. As for updating a sub task it so much depends on how the rest,of,your code is structured.

Answer (score 0):

While I won't mark this as *the* answer, as it's actually a workaround, I'll post that I did meet my objective by ignoring the more elegant relational approach of reflexive subtask and just adding two attributes to my parent class:

1. parentTaskID: Double
2. isSubtask: Bool

Using this, I can easily fetch a list of parent tasks without the subtasks and I can easily get the subtasks for a particular parent.

It would be great if there were more literature on how to interact with reflexive relationships in Coredata CRUD functions but for now this less graceful solution will do.

Comment: There is nothing in this solution that you can’t already do with the existing superTask and subTasks properties.

Comment: That much I expected, I assume the relationship route has benefits over this approach. It's simply that understanding the model only gave me enough to read taskobject.subtasks - however, how to add new subtasks or, once I populate a table with those tasks, then updating the model with edits... there wasn't enough example code and literature on this. My apps go out into production and serve existing users so I don't implement things if I can't find sufficient code to know I fully understand them, can implement them right, fix bugs, etc.